# Selected Content is not displaying in the textbox

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

Windows application

Form (Gridview and Textbox)

GridView1

```
ID Name

001 Rajan
002 Sajan
103 Prathev
104 vijayan
....
```

Conditon

When i clicked the up and down arrow (keyboard) in the Gridview1 (id or name row), then selected cell should display in the textbox and also when i enter some numbers means, that entered number should appear in the textbox and 
also entered related ID or name should display in the gridview1

For Example

If i press 0, that 0 should display in the textbox, and gridview display like

```
ID Name

001 Rajan
002 Sajan
```

If i press 1, that 1 should display in the textbox, and gridview display like

```
ID Name

103 Prathev
104 vijayan
```

Tried Code for displyaing in the girdview

```
Dim conObjects As New ConnectionObjects
        conObjects.OpenConnection()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim ada As SqlDataAdapter
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select ID, Name from employee where id like '%" & textbox1.Text & "%' ", conObjects.myConnection)
        ada = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        ada.Fill(ds, "employee")
        gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Expected answer

```
-> In which gridview event i have to write a code
-> If i press up or down arrow, then selected cell should display in the textbox
-> If i enter some number or characters, that numbers or character should display in the textbox and selected related values should display in the gridview
```

How to do this.

Need help or vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your `dataSource` to `dataGridview` and `TextBoxes`.

Here is sample code (Add dataGridView1, TextBox1,TextBox2):

```
 Private Sub YourForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("No")
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "A")
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "B")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "No")
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Name")
    End Sub
```

Comment: How to focus the textbox, when i enter any character or no, then textbox should be focus automatically... code textbox1.focus()